# How to properly import wampy into TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, websocket, wamp

How to properly import wampy into TypeScript project?

[Wampy.js](https://github.com/KSDaemon/wampy.js) installed with

`typings install dt~wampy --global --save && npm install wampy --save`

Trying to import Wampy:

`import {Wampy} from "wampy";`

`npm start` produces this error:

`error TS2305: Module '"wampy"' has no exported member 'Wampy'.`

Next I tried to import as I have seen [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-import-wampy-and-using-it/57896/3):

`import * as Wampy from "wampy";`

Getting

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Wampy'.`

Answer (score 1):

If it helps to someone
I manually added

`<script src="node_modules/wampy/build/wampy.min.js"></script>`

to index.html and declared Wampy as any (as I posted [posted](https://github.com/KSDaemon/wampy.js/issues/23#issuecomment-238114610)):

`declare var Wampy: any;`

And it works now.